# getElementByID loop returning null

Tags: javascript

Chrome developer tools says that the value function doesn't work on a null value and points to the line in the for loop. Why isn't getElementByID fetching my values? (this is a refactor, getElement work perfect with the actual values typed in).

```
locationStops = ["start","end"];
var stopNum = locationStops.length;
var stopAddresses = [];
for(val in locationStops) {
stopAddresses.push(document.getElementById(val).value);
}
```

Comment: `console.log(val);` --- it makes sense to ALWAYS check variables hold the value you expect.

Comment: Also, DOM id are supposed to be unique. Not sure why you need a loop.

Comment: Don't use `for..in`, try `var locationStops = ["start", "end"],
    stopNum = locationStops.length,
    stopAddresses = [];

for(val i = 0; i < locationStops.length; i++) {
    stopAddresses.push(document.getElementById(locationStops[i]).value);
}`

Comment: @e.sterling That's the key, use `for` as in ^^^^ comment

Comment: Your val refers to 0,1 etc. So there must be elements with ID's 0,1. If you want values in array, use locationStops[val].

Comment: yes, that was the key, thank you @Tushar. Can someone explain why this is so?

Comment: `for (val of locationStops)`?

Comment: @e.sterling Already explained. `key` is numeric sequential `0`, `1`, ... and you dont' have the elements with the id `0`, `1`, so `getElementById` returns `null`.

Comment: Debug your program. Either add a `console.log` as suggested in an earlier comment, or set a breakpoint on the `stopAddresses.push` line, and examine the value of `val` there. You would have found the problem quite quickly I imagine.

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid the for loop, and the potential for bugs that you ran into with, by using `map`:

```
stopAddresses = locationStops . map(function(id) { 
  return document.getElementById(id).value;
});
```

Depending on your stylistic preferences, you might find the following more readable:

```
function get_value_from_id(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id).value; 
}

stopAddresses = locationStops . map(get_value_from_id);
```

If you want to use a loop, you could use the new `for...of` construct:

```
for (let val of locationStops) {
             ^^
  stopAddresses.push(document.getElementById(val).value);
}
```

If you have an environment that supports ES7 array comprehensions:

```
[ for (id of locationStops) document.getElementById(id).value ]
```

If you want to stick with your `for...in` loop, then as other answers have pointed out, the loop variable is the index, not the value, so you have to access the ID with `locationStops[i]`, but you are better off using a regular for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `for in` for arrays.

Use a simple for loop instead.

```
var a = ["start", "end"];
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
{
 console.log(document.getElementById(a[i]).value);
}
```

---

You can use for-in also but, it is not recommended as it results in unexpected behaviour sometimes.

`val` refers to `0,1` etc. So there must be elements with ID's `0,1`.

```
for(var val in a)
{
 console.log(document.getElementById(a[val]).value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because your for loop syntax is incorrect

Try This

```
var locationStops = ["start","end"];
var stopNum = locationStops.length;
var stopAddresses = [];
for(i = 0; i < locationStops.length; i++) {
stopAddresses.push(document.getElementById(locationStops[i]).value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use `Array.prototype.map`.

```
var locationStops = ["start","end"];
var stopAddresses = locationStops.map(function(val) {
  return document.getElementById(val).value;
});
```

Honestly, though, looping over a two element array is kind of silly and if it was my code I would even prefer to simply assign each address directly.

```
var stopAddresses = [document.getElementById("start").value, document.getElementById("end").value];
```